# How to create lists of automatically and manually selected citations at the end of every chapter?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, bibtex, natbib

I have document with multiple chapters. I want two bibliography lists at the end of every chapter - one list for references cited in chapter and second one for manually pointed references (the `bibentry` stuff).

So far I am able to create separate bibliographies for every chapter with these modules:

```
\usepackage[square,numbers,sectionbib]{natbib}
\usepackage{chapterbib}
\usepackage{bibentry}
```

However, I struggle to attach not-cited references in the separate bibliography list. I end up with this code at end of every chapter:

\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
    \bibliography{refs1}

```
\begin{enumerate}[label={[\arabic*]}]
    \item \bibentry{entry1}
    \item \bibentry{entry2}
\end{enumerate}
```

It correctly displays two bibliographies. However the `bibentries` (manual references from second list) are also displayed in the first bibliography, although they have not been cited in particular chapter!

How can I tell to latex that manual `bibentries` should not be in the first (automated) bibliography?

Comment: Do you want to continue using `natbib` and `chapterbib`? Or are you open to use `biblatex` with Biber as your tagging suggests?

Comment: @moewe I am open to every reasonable solution.